# void vs null vs undefined in TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a Box class which simply contains one value and a method to print said value:

```
class Box<T> {
    private value: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    display(): void {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

I'd like to get to the idea of an 'empty box'. A specific use case would be that the Box is an event, and the generic type T gives additional information about the event. For some events, no additional information is required, all that has to be known is that the event occured.

For such a case, I have three options:

```
var vBox = new Box<void>(?);
var uBox = new Box<undefined>(undefined);
var nBox = new Box<null>(null);
```

Using `void` as a type here seems unintuitive and I don't know what I'd give the constructor. And, although I know the difference between `null` and `undefined`, it isn't clear to me which one I should use in this case.

Comment: The class in your example has no need to be generic, since `value` is private and `T` only appears once in the public interface (in the constructor). The natural way to construct an "empty" box would simply be `new Box()`, and it shouldn't matter whether the private field is `null` or `undefined` as long as the `display` method does what you want it to.

Comment: An empty box is a box without contents, which, to me, means its contents are null; it has a value, but it is meaningless. If the empty box had no value and no contents, perhaps a "Heisenbox", then perhaps undefined would be more appropriate. But really, it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an empty box you can use the [Null Object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). A class that extends `Box<null>` and does not provide any way to change its content:

```js
class EmptyBox extends Box<null> {
  public constructor() {
    super(null);
  }

  // overload here any method of class Box that modify its properties
  // with versions that do nothing
}
```